# How can I join a posts table and comments table so that I can sort my results by the posts with the highest number of comments?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I can't seem to figure this out. I need the help of your genius minds. I have a function that returns all posts. But I need to be able to sort them by the posts with the highest number of comments. Here is my PHP function with SQL in it.

```
function GetNewsfeedPosts( $matches, $user_id, $show_more_post, $followers = 0)
{
    global $DBConnection;
    $groups = $this->SubscribedGroupsIDs($user_id);/* get all of the groups that I am a part of */
    $union  = '';/* declare the variable */
    $ratingQuery = 'p_id';/* declare the variable and set the default to all ratings */
    /*----------------filtering the home posts----------------*/
    if($_SESSION['ratingFilter'] == 0) {/* if the selected rating filter is all ratings then */
        $ratingQuery = 'p_id';
    } else if($_SESSION['ratingFilter'] == 1) {/* if the selected rating filter is most loves then */
        $ratingQuery = 'likes';
    } else if($_SESSION['ratingFilter'] == 2) {/* if the selected rating filter is most comments then */
        $ratingQuery = 'likes';
    } else if($_SESSION['ratingFilter'] == 3) {/* if the selected rating filter is most shares then */
        $ratingQuery = 'likes';
    } else if($_SESSION['ratingFilter'] == 4) {/* if the selected rating filter is most views then */
        $ratingQuery = 'likes';
    }

    if($groups != 0)
    {
        $union = "UNION ALL
                    ( 
                        SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.is_profile_notes,wallposts.times_viewed,
                        wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
                        wallposts.totaluploads,wallposts.WallUploadID,wallposts.type,
                        wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,
                        wallposts.privacy,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.with_friends_tagged,wallposts.emotion_head,wallposts.selected_emotion,wallposts.title,
                        wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,
                        wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,
                        wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, 
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,

                        PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic, PosterTable.gender as posterGender,PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid, PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
                        PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
                        PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,wallposts.date_created 

                        FROM 

                        wallusers,wallusers as PosterTable, wallposts 

                        LEFT JOIN walllikes_track ON wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id AND walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 

                        WHERE 
                        wallusers.active = 1 
                        AND PosterTable.active = 1 AND 
                        wallposts.group_id IN (".$groups.")  AND wallposts.group_id != 0
                        AND PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by AND wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."
                        AND wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by ) "; 
    }

    if($followers != 0)
    {
        $union .= "UNION ALL
                    ( 
                        SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.is_profile_notes,wallposts.times_viewed,
                        wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
                        wallposts.totaluploads,wallposts.WallUploadID,wallposts.type,
                        wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,
                        wallposts.privacy,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.with_friends_tagged,
                        wallposts.emotion_head,wallposts.selected_emotion,wallposts.title,
                        wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,
                        wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,
                        wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, 
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,

                        PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic, 
                        PosterTable.gender as posterGender,
                        PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid, 
                        PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
                        PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,
                        PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
                        PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,
                        walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,
                        wallposts.date_created 

                        FROM 

                        wallusers,wallusers as PosterTable, 
                        wallposts LEFT JOIN walllikes_track ON wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id AND walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 

                        WHERE 
                        wallusers.active = 1 
                        AND PosterTable.active = 1 AND
                        wallusers.mem_id IN (".$followers.") 

                        AND wallposts.privacy = 1

                        AND PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by  

                        AND wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."

                        AND wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid ) ";    
    }

    // updated for groups
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM (
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.is_profile_notes,wallposts.times_viewed,
                wallposts.marked,wallposts.secure_id,wallposts.reshared,wallposts.group_id,
                wallposts.totaluploads,wallposts.WallUploadID,wallposts.type,
                wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,
                wallposts.privacy,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.with_friends_tagged,
                wallposts.emotion_head,wallposts.selected_emotion,wallposts.title,
                wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,
                wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,
                wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, 
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,

                PosterTable.mem_pic as posterPic, 
                PosterTable.gender as posterGender,
                PosterTable.oauth_uid as poster_oauth_uid, 
                PosterTable.username as posterUsername, 
                PosterTable.mem_fname as posterFname,
                PosterTable.work as posterWork, 
                PosterTable.mem_lname as posterLname,

                walllikes_track.id as PostLikeFound,
                wallposts.date_created 

                FROM 

                wallusers,wallusers as PosterTable, 
                wallposts LEFT JOIN walllikes_track ON wallposts.p_id = walllikes_track.post_id AND walllikes_track.member_id = ".$user_id." 

                WHERE 
                wallusers.active = 1 
                AND PosterTable.active = 1 AND
                (wallusers.mem_id IN (".$matches.") OR wallusers.mem_id = ".$user_id.")

                AND PosterTable.mem_id = wallposts.posted_by  AND wallposts.marked < ".$this->flagNumber."

                AND wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid )

                ".$union ."
            ) 
            results
            order by $ratingQuery desc limit ".$show_more_post.", 10"; 

    // GROUP PRIVACY 
    // 2 = public, 
    // 1 = closed, 
    // 0 = secret       

    // POSTS PRIVACY 
    // pub = 1 
    // annoy = 2
    // on newsfeed, show all posts including public, annoymous and even those are not friends. AND wallposts.privacy != 2

    $res = mysqli_query($DBConnection, $qry);
    return $res;
}
```

The table with comments in it is called "wallcomments" it has the columns post_id, Comment_id etc. How can I join these two tables in one query so that I can return the posts with the most number of comments. I don't know where to put the join clause or the select cause I don't know how to go about writing it. Please help.

Comment: I think you need to watch about counting rows in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: Use a left join with wallcomments, and add a group by.

Comment: Okay thanks. I have looked into the counting rows in sql. But it's still not clear to me how to do it for this Query. Does the order of the JOINS matter? where should I include the LEFT JOIN in the QUERY?